# How to send 2 HTTP requests in NestJS with built-in HttpService

Tags: axios, nestjs

I'd like to send 2 requests at the same time when one of my NestJS endpoints are called. I'm using Cloudant, and with the endpoint call I'd like to reach and do something with 2 different documents in 2 different databases. To be exact, I want to create a new document in one of the databases and modify another already existing document in another database.

This is the endpoint in my `controller`:

```
@Put()
createEntry(@Body() body: { title: string; description: string }): Observable<{ ok: boolean; id: string; rev: string }> {
  return this.entriesService.createEntry(body);
}
```

This is my `entriesService`:

```
createEntry(body: Entry): Observable<{ ok: boolean; id: string; rev: string }> {
  this.userService.modifyOtherDocument(body); // I'd like to execute this here
  return this.httpService.put(`${environment.cloudantBaseUrl}/entries/${uuidv4()}`, body).pipe(map((response) => response.data));
}
```

This method should call another method in another service, called `userService` like this:

```
modifyOtherDocument(body: Entry): Observable<{ ok: boolean; id: string; rev: string }> {
  return this.httpService.put(`${environment.cloudantBaseUrl}/other_db/${body.id}`, body).pipe(map((response) => response.data));
}
```

Both service methods work perfectly if I call them separately. But as soon as I want to call the other method in my `userService` from my `entriesService` method the document in `other_db` won't be updated at all.

How should I make this working? I'm using NestJS' built-in `HttpService` from `@nestjs/axios`. It doesn't matter in which order they'll be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest's `HttpService` uses `Observable`s from `RxJS`. They're kind of like callbacks, but don't fire until there's something actually observing it, whether this is a `.subscribe()` or a `lastValueFrom` method. What you can do here is make use of the Observable pipeline like so and have both events fired one after the other

```js
createEntry(body: Entry): Observable<{ ok: boolean; id: string; rev: string }> {
  return this.userService.modifyOtherDocument(body).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.httpService.put(`${environment.cloudantBaseUrl}/entries/${uuidv4()}`, body)),
    map((response) => response.data))
  );
}
```

This will make the first observable resolve and then call the second one to take its place. [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io) has some good resources on learning RxJS if you're interested

Comment: minor typo `switchMap`*

Comment: Perfect, thank you! ;)